# Can delay sensor be use for a distance?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Can the "delay sensor" be use for a distance and not for a number of frames?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless you want to multiply the number of frames with the speed per frame of the object.

You can, however, use the `Near` sensor for this effect. For more details on how to do this, please add some more info on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create an airplane and to limit the rotation when is taking off for 100 units (meters).